# Installshield multi-language issues

Tags: localization, internationalization, windows-installer, globalization, installshield

I've drawn the short straw at work and I have to support the Installshield 2009 setup application.  When I open the .ISM file in InstallShield 2009 Professional I get this message:

The following languages will be disabled as they were included in this project but are not installed on this system:
Chinese (Traditional)
German
French (France)
Italian
Swedish
Chinese (Simplified)

Do I need to install something in Windows XP, or do I need to install something in InstallShield?  Any insight would be very valuable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I need Installshield Premier and not Installshield Professional (which is the one I have).

Answer (score 1):

You need Premier instead of Professional for multilingual setups. If you can't afford the upgrade, I'd suggest migrating to WiX.